# Geoalchemy2 "No Module Named Utils"

Tags: geoalchemy2

I am trying to use GeoAlchemy2 with Python 3.5 and get this following error:

```
from geoalchemy import Geometry
from geoalchemy.base import *
from utils import from_wkt
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: Actually you are ussing GeoAlchemy "1" not 2. Regarding your issue, it is an open issue yet, see https://github.com/geoalchemy/geoalchemy/issues/41